# For the MCU STM32F103C8T6 : What is the boundry address for reset and clock control registers

Tags: c, embedded, iot, microcontroller, microprocessors

What is difference between address and boundry address,how to find the reset registers address and clock control register address using datasheet.
https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/389/cd00161566-1796535.pdf
DATA SHEET LINK

Answer (score 3):

> how to find the reset registers address and clock control register address using datasheet.

You don't; that information is in the reference manual: https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

The data sheet is the source for specific pin-out, package options, electrical and environmental characteristics, and contains only a summary of the components on the die (peripherals, memory, core).

Note also that there is a third document that defines important aspects of the STM32F103 that is neither in the data sheet nor the reference manual.  That is the flash programming manual: https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/cd00283419-stm32f10xxx-flash-memory-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf  (confusingly called the "Programming Manual", but there is another document with that name about the the programming *model*).  That deals with flash programming/erasure and options byte configuration.

Familiarise yourself with all the resources available at https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f103.html#documentation I suggest - there are other useful documents about this device.

Comment: I always find it strange that F103's flash is documented in a separate file. Other series have this section included in the main *Reference Manual*.

Comment: @Tagli  yes it is a bit of a gotcha too, because hidden in that document is the gem that erasing or writing the flash causes the bus to stall and so code execution to stop - for several tens of milliseconds for a page erase.  So writing flash in-application messes up interrupt latency and timing potentially catastrophically.  STM32F205/215/207/217 also have a separate manual (and the larger page size means the latency is several 100's milliseconds).  On other flash devices, only the page being written/erased is inaccessible during programming - STM32 is I think unusual in this respect.

Answer (score 2):

Microcontrollers come with two main documentation files:

- The *datasheet* contains information to the electronics hardware designer.
- The *user/reference manual* contains information to the software designer.

You need the latter, which you shouldn't go look for at some catalog vendor but at the manufacturer's web site for that part.